# Basics of this web application development

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, servlets, web-applications

I am creating a payroll system. I have a database which contains employee_id and password. My index.html is the login page, where you enter an employee_id and password and the database checks to see if the details are correct and if it is, then the Welcome.java servlet takes you to a page which prints "Welcome user".

What I want is, when an employee logs in, it takes them to a page with the following buttons instead of a screen which simply says "Welcome user":

View personal information, View payslip information, change password

I do not know how to do this.

Below are my files.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="login" method="post">
<h3>
Employee Login
</h3>
 <b>Employee ID:</b> <br>
 <input type="text"name="employee_id" size="20"><br><br>
<b>Password:</b><br>
<input type="password" name="password" size="20"><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Login"><br><br>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Login.java (servlet)**

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class Login extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        String employee_id = request.getParameter("employee_id");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");
        if(Validate.checkUser(employee_id, password)) { 
            RequestDispatcher rs = request.getRequestDispatcher("Welcome");
            rs.forward(request, response);
        }
        else
        {
           out.println("Employee ID or Password is incorrect. Please try again.");
           RequestDispatcher rs = request.getRequestDispatcher("index.html");
           rs.include(request, response);
        }
    }  


        }
```

**Validate.java (class file)**

```
import java.sql.*;
public class Validate
{
    public static boolean checkUser(String employee_id, String password)
    {
        boolean st = false;
        try { 
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/payroll_system", "root", ""); 
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("select * from employee_login where employeeID = ? and pwd = ?");
            ps.setString(1, employee_id);
            ps.setString(2, password);
            ResultSet rs =ps.executeQuery();
             st = rs.next();

         }catch(Exception e)
          {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
             return st;                 
      }   
    }
```

**Welcome.java (servlet)**

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class Welcome extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("Welcome user");
      }  
}
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" >

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>login</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>Login</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Welcome</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>Welcome</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>login</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Welcome</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/Welcome</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to change one line of code of  login servlet `RequestDispatcher rs = request.getRequestDispatcher("Welcome"); as             RequestDispatcher rs = request.getRequestDispatcher("Options");`
and create a html file of creating 3 buttons.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Options</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form action="Mainservlet" method="post">
    <h3>
Options
</h3>

    <input type="submit" value="Personalinformation" name="pi">
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="PayslipInformation" name="psi">
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="ChangePassword" name="cp">
    <br>
    <br>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

> In mainservlet

```
if(request.getParameter("pi") != null) {
// Invoke PersonalInformation's job here.
} else if (request.getParameter("psi") != null) {
// Invoke PayslipInformation's job here.
}else if (request.getParameter("cp") != null) {
// Invoke ChangePassword's job here.
}
```

Comment: How should I configure my web.xml to match these changes?

Answer (score -1):

Create an html or jsp page with your buttons and other content, then redirect from login servlet to your page instead of welcome servlet through request dispatcher or just by response.sendRedirect() method.